# http Redirect an azure web application

Tags: linux, azure-web-app-service, tomcat9

My company has an azure linux web application that is running tomcat 9.0.

I need to setup a http 307 redirect to direct uses to another website (not hosted on azure).

I came across this article on how to do a redirect on a web app:
https://michelebusta.com/azure-tip-just-a-web-app-with-redirect-please-a045d1072659

But I think the article only applies to Windows instances.

How do you accomplish this on a web app that's running in linux?

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish a URL rewrite on an Apache Linux Web App, you can follow the below process.

1. Create an htaccess file in /home/site/wwwroot/ of your site.
2. Use the [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to develop a similar rule as below. The below example is [rewriting URLs from HTTP to HTTPS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/06/19/http-to-https-redirect-for-azure-web-app-on-linux/).

   - RewriteEngine On
   - RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-ARR-SSL} ^$
   - RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]